# must be modifiable value error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, syntax-error

below is a .cpp file that i am including in another .cpp file.  I am getting an error that states emp.grosPay() must be a modifiable lvalue.  any ideas on fixing it?

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "weeklyEmp.h"

using namespace std;

const double WEEKLY_ALLOWANCE = 39.42;
const double FICA_TAX_RATE = 0.0765;
weeklyEmp::weeklyEmp()
{
    my_name = ?name?;
}
weeklyEmp::weeklyEmp(string initName,
    double initHours,
    double initRate,
    int initExemptions,
    string initFilingStatus)
{
    my_name; initName;
    my_hours; initHours;
    my_rate; initRate;
    my_exemptions; initExemptions;
    my_filingStatus; initFilingStatus;
}

//--modifiers

void weeklyEmp::set_hours(double thisWeeksHours)
    //post: Set the hours worked for a given week
{
    my_hours = thisWeeksHours;
}



void weeklyEmp::set_rate(double thisWeeksRate)
//post: Change the employee's hourly rate of pay
{
 my_rate = thisWeeksRate;
}

//--accessors
double weeklyEmp::grosPay() const
//post: Return gross pay with overtime

{if(my_hours <=40) return my_hours * my_rate;
else
return (40*my_rate) + (my_hours-40) * 1.5 * my_rate;
}

double weeklyEmp::incomeTax() const
//post: Return the federal income tax
{
double result(0.0);
double taxableIncome(grosPay() - my_exemptions * WEEKLY_ALLOWANCE); 
if(my_filingStatus == "S" || my_filingStatus == "s")
{
if (taxableIncome <= 23.00)
result = 0.00;
else if(taxableIncome <= 397.00)
result = 0.15 * (taxableIncome - 23.00);
else if(taxableIncome <= 928.00)
result = 56.10 + 0.28 * (taxableIncome - 397.00);
else if(taxableIncome <= 2121.00)
result = 204.78 + 0.33 * (taxableIncome - 928.00);
else
result = 598.47 + 0.28 * (taxableIncome - 2121.00);
} 
if(my_filingStatus == "M" || my_filingStatus == "m")
{
if(taxableIncome <= 65.00)
result = 0.00;
else if(taxableIncome <= 689.00)
result = 0.15 * (taxableIncome - 65.00);
else if(taxableIncome <= 1573.00)
result = 93.60 + 0.28 * (taxableIncome - 689.00);
else if(taxableIncome <= 3858.00)
result = 341.12 + 0.33 * (taxableIncome - 1573.00);
else
result = 1095.17 + 0.28 * (taxableIncome - 3858.00);
} 
/* round to the nearest penny */
/* include compfun.cpp for round function */
result =(result, 2);  
return result;
}

double weeklyEmp::FICATax() const
//post: Return the social security tax
{
    return grosPay() * FICA_TAX_RATE; 
}

string weeklyEmp::name() const
//post: Return the employee's name

{ return my_name;

}
```

The portion of code with the error is below and marked ***  ****

```
int main()
{
    string name;
    double rate;
    double hours;
    int exemptions;
    string filingStatus;


    cout <<"Name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Hourly Rate:";
    cin >> rate;
    cout << "Hours Worked:";
    cin >> hours;
    cout << "Exemptions: ";
    cin >> exemptions;
    cout<< "S) ingle / M) arried: ";
    cin >> filingStatus;
    cout << " " << endl;

    weeklyEmp emp(name, hours, rate, exemptions, filingStatus);
    double net = ***emp.grosPay()*** = emp.incomeTax() - emp.FICATax();

}
```

Comment: `grosPay()` returns an rvalue, you can't assign to that. What is the intention of that line?

Comment: What's `my_name = ?name?;`?

Comment: i added "?name?'  it was a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double net = emp.grosPay() = emp.incomeTax() - emp.FICATax();
//                        ^^^
```

`grosPay` doesn't return a reference, so I'm assuming you didn't mean to use an `=` sign there. May have been a slip of the thumb.

Did you mean to use the minus operator `-`?:

```
double net = emp.grosPay() - emp.incomeTax() - emp.FICATax();
//                        ^^^
```

The error was occurring because you can't modify a `const` object, an object returned by a `const` function, or an rvalue that isn't bound to a non-const rvalue-reference.

Comment: Consensus not only on the solution, but on the use of carets.

Answer (score 0):

```
double net = ***emp.grosPay()*** = emp.incomeTax() - emp.FICATax();
                                ^^^
```

The second '=' should be a '-' sign; I think you're trying to subtract, not assign.